How to disable WireMock server for a single test?
I'm writing tests for my Spring Boot service. I use Wiremock for mocking HTTP requests. I need to disable the WireMock server temporarily for one specific test to simulate the unavailability of the external service.
Here is my current test class:
@SpringBootTest(classes = {ArticleService.class, ArticleServiceTest.TestConfig.class})
@WireMockTest(httpPort = 8080, proxyMode = true)
public class ArticleServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private ArticleService articleService;

    @TestConfiguration
    public static class TestConfig {
        @Bean
        @Primary
        public ArticleServiceConfiguration articleServiceConfiguration() {
            ArticleServiceConfiguration configuration = Mockito.mock(ArticleServiceConfiguration.class);
            Mockito.when(configuration.getUri()).thenReturn(URI.create("http://article-service:8080"));
            return configuration;
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void saveArticle() {
        // This test works well
        String expectedJson = """
                    {
                        "title": "Test Title",
                        "content": "Test Content",
                        "creatorId": 1
                    }""";

        stubFor(post(urlEqualTo("/internal/articles"))
                .withHost(equalTo("article-service"))
                .willReturn(ok()));

        ArticleDto dto = new ArticleDto("Test Title", "Test Content", 1L);
        articleService.saveArticle(dto);

        verify(postRequestedFor(urlEqualTo("/internal/articles"))
                .withRequestBody(equalToJson(expectedJson)));
    }

    @Test
    public void saveArticleWhenServerIsUnavailable() {
        // How to disable the wiremock server here?
        ArticleDto dto = new ArticleDto("Test Title", "Test Content", 1L);
        assertThrows(ServerUnavailableException.class, () -> articleService.saveArticle(dto));
    }
}

So how can I properly stop the WireMock server for a single test while keeping it enabled for others?

This question is similar to: Is it possible to simulate connection timeout using wiremock tools?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You can simulate the effect of WireMock being down by configuring it to drop the connection to the client with a RST packet. This is what most network stacks will do when you attempt to connect to a port that isn't open:
stubFor(any(anyUrl())
  .willReturn(aResponse().withFault(Fault.CONNECTION_RESET_BY_PEER)));

